# How to define/write these atomic operations on Linux GCC

Tags: linux, multithreading, atomic, operation

I am writing an application, this application is an implementation of lock-free queue and will be running on linux and compiled by **GCC 3.4.2**.

The implementation is based on following atomic operations:

__sync_fetch_and_add

**__sync_fetch_and_sub**

**__sync_bool_compare_and_swap**

**__sync_val_compare_and_swap****

The problem is GCC doesn't have the above builtins until **GCC 4.1**, so currently I have to define them myself in assembly language. But I know nothing about assembly, can anybody give me the defintions of above function? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

More information:

/// @brief atomically adds a_count to the variable pointed by a_ptr
/// @return the value that had previously been in memory
__sync_fetch_and_add

/// @brief atomically substracts a_count from the variable pointed by a_ptr
/// @return the value that had previously been in memory
__sync_fetch_and_sub

/// @brief Compare And Swap
///        If the current value of *a_ptr is a_oldVal, then write a_newVal into *a_ptr
/// @return true if the comparison is successful and a_newVal was written
__sync_bool_compare_and_swap

/// @brief Compare And Swap
///        If the current value of *a_ptr is a_oldVal, then write a_newVal into *a_ptr
/// @return the contents of *a_ptr before the operation
__sync_val_compare_and_swap(a_ptr, a_oldVal, a_newVal)

Comment: If you upgrade to a modern version of the compiler, instead of relying on something that's very _very_ old, you have [atomic functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) built into the standard C++ library.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks Joachim, but I am working for the company, and the machines it has are so old that they can't install gcc 4.1, so  I have to write them myself. Do you have more suggestion?

Comment: You can build a modern GCC with the old GCC, there is no need to go any other route.

Comment: what do you mean "build a modern GCC with the old GCC"? Is there any way to upgrade the GCC 3.4 to GCC 4.1 on Fedora 3(2.6)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Untested, may contain typos):

```
inline long
val_compare_and_swap(volatile long *ptr, long old, long _new) {
    long prev;
    asm volatile("lock;"
#if defined(__amd64__)
                 "cmpxchgq %1, %2;"
#else
                 "cmpxchgl %1, %2;"
#endif
                 : "=a"(prev)
                 : "q"(_new), "m"(*ptr), "a"(old)
                 : "memory");
    return prev;
}

inline int
bool_compare_and_swap(volatile long *ptr, long old, long _new) {
    return val_compare_and_swap(ptr, old, new) == old;
}

inline long
fetch_and_add(volatile long *ptr, long value) {
    long prev;
    do {
        prev = *ptr;
    } until (bool_compare_and_swap(ptr, prev, prev + value));
    return prev;
}
```

If you need a compare_and_swap that operates on a two-words value rather than just one, see e.g. http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/third_party/tcmalloc/chromium/src/base/atomicops-internals-x86.h.